# How upload folder by FTP using cURL?

Tags: python, curl, ftp, pycurl

I need to create FTP-uploader, i am using pycurl and python, but i dont know how to make folder with cURL on ftp's host. Help me please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the curl option while uploading a file : --ftp-create-dirs

- http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--ftp-create-dirs

Ex:

```
curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u username:password ftp://sitename.com/directory/myfile
```